# Altium 3D not showing textures

Tags: pcb, altium, 3d

i Finished my design and now im  trying to make it fully 3D with STEP 214 models formwww.3dcontentcentral.es however as you can see even when im gettign the right models they just look like this, when the preview of the terminal blcok and the other compoenets actually look like the 2nd pic, am i doing something wrong or is there any configuration i skipped?

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

looks like the colors are there however they become grey as sooon as the get near the PCB

Comment: yeah, you didnt attached the STEP model to the component/footprint.

Comment: Sorry I just realized that yes the models are there, but the colour is overridden. There may be a 3D model colour option somewhere which is forcing it to go grey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step AP203 does not seem to preserve colors, whereas AP213 does. Not sure about "textures", but neither seem to support transparency. If you're just downloading random 3D files from the internet, maybe they're not exactly in the advertised format.

For the ones that look like blocks, make sure that in the 3D body you've selected "Generic STEP Model" rather than "extruded", and of course you must embed and place it properly.

Edit: with the further information -- You've got a collision there- perhaps you have the highlight color set to gray rather than the typical virulent green. Maybe you've placed the bodies so they intersect the PCB surface. Since you didn't make them - they might be made with a plane not optimal for Altium, and just need to nudged up a hair. Also make sure you reset error markers.

Comment: yes you got it, apparently i have some errors in the PCB so its affecting my entire circuit, i tested changing the ERC color to another one and all the models are now that same color